# Как из Dictionary сделать двумерный динамический массив?

Tags: c#, массивы, сниппет

Есть заполненный `Dictionary<string, string> DicVer = new Dictionary<string, string>();`  подскажите, пожалуйста, каким способом можно из него создать двумерный динамический массив?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Альтернативное и более `verbose` решение:*

```
private static string[,] ConvertDictionaryTo2dStringArray(
    Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    string[,] stringArray = new string[2, dictionary.Count];

    int i = 0;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> item in dictionary)
    {
        stringArray[0, i] = item.Key;
        stringArray[1, i] = item.Value;
        i++;
    }

    return stringArray;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Dictionary<string, string> DicVer = new Dictionary<string, string>();

DicVer.Add("key1","value1");
DicVer.Add("key2","value2");
DicVer.Add("key3","value3");

var result = DicVer.Select(el => new string[]{el.Key, el.Value}).ToArray();

// вариант использования
foreach(var subArray in result)
{
    foreach(var el in subArray)
    {
        Console.Write(el+"  ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

result[1][1].Dump(); // value2
DicVer.Select((el,i)=>i==1 ? el.Value : String.Empty).First(el=>el!=String.Empty).Dump(); // value2
DicVer.GetValue(1).Dump(); // value2
```

> нужно по индексу обратится к элементу
> (по порядковому номеру)

Чтобы обращаеться к словарю по индексу, напишем Extension method:

```
public static class DictExt
{
    public static U GetValue<T,U>(this Dictionary<T,U> dict, int idx) where U : class
    {
        return dict.Select((el,i)=>i==idx ? el.Value : null).First(el=>el!=null);
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо большое, пока закрывать не буду, может еще варинты какие кто напишет. А как кстати обращатся к вновь созданному массиву, напишите пример если не сложно
Upd: да я все эти преобразования то только из-за того пытаюсь делать, что нужно по индексу обратится к элементу (по порядковому номеру)

Comment: А почему бы вам сразу не формировать индексный массив? И вы уверены, что последовательность всегда будет одна и та же всегда?

Comment: да, последовательность точно будет одна и та же. Наверно действительно сразу лучше записывать в двумерный индексный массив, я словарем воспользовался потому что он добвляет только уникальные ключи, придется проверку на сравнение писать тогда со всеми остальными элементами в массиве.

Comment: Спасибо буду знать, я думал SortedDictionary это бинарное дерево, а что Вы имели ввиду когда предупреждали, есть какие то подводные камни или серьезные отличия в расположении данных?

Comment: о чёрт, вы правы, я ошибся!